# Is sending the same e-mail encrypted and also unencrypted a security risk?

Tags: encryption, pgp, gnupg

Is it a risk, if I send the same email one time encrypted and to another recipient unencrypted?

I wonder if it would be possible to calculate the decryption key (if someone had a copy of both) and then also be able to decrypt other encrypted emails I send?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not a risk at all with any secure cryptosystem, especially a crypto-system that use asymmetric encryption (e.g., has public keys and private keys) like PGP.  If that was a risk, then any time you sent someone an encrypted message that they have permission to decrypt, they would be able to recover your private key by possessing both the decrypted message and the received encrypted message.

Even with symmetric encryption when used properly (e.g., in well-designed secure software), there will be no risk.  If you use symmetric encryption improperly there will be a risk.  E.g., if you use a block cipher in counter (CTR) mode with a repeated initialization vector, then this has the flaw of the [many-time-pad](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6020/many-time-pad-attack).  That said, re-using an initialization vector in a stream cipher mode like this is a flaw in and of itself and doesn't require an attacker to have access to the plaintext, just multiple ciphertexts with the same IV -- though having a plaintext and ciphertext makes the attack completely trivial.

Answer (score 0):

No it would not be a risk for your given scenario. If the email is encrypted using an industry accepted cryptographic method then someone having the plaintext and ciphertext versions learns nothing about the key used.

I know you didn't ask, but there are other risks such as an attacker having the ability to man in the middle the email server, they could now know what was sent in the encrypted email by reading the none encrypted email (assuming the attacker has the ability to work out they are the same content).